# Where do these <em> elements are coming from in my HTML code?

Tags: html, drupal, drupal-6

For some reason  elements are added to my html code and the text is rendered as italic.

http://109.72.95.174/astudio/sites/lancelmaat/performanceinstallation?tid=22(see bottom lines, or content of menu "Contact")

I'm using CKEditor in Drupal for the input of some text areas.

But it is strange, because the  elements are added only for specific pages...

Also, I cannot see the  elements in Safari Developer bar (I only see style: italic), but I think this is a smaller detail.

thanks

Comment: I don't see any em tags.

Comment: @mirzu Are you using Safari developer tab, or Firefox ? I only see them with Firefox, Safari just add style:italic in css

Comment: There is no <em> in the HTML source, and the text doesn't appear to be italic. Where exactly are you seeing these things?

Comment: @Mirzu and @Scott Reynen Sorry, the url was toa different page. That's a point. I've updated the question with an example of page with the anomaly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of your nodes ("a live library") has on unclosed `<em>` in the message body, near the sentence that says "Voorjaar 1998 werd ik uitgenodigd doo..."

This is (accidentally) incorrect HTML, but different browsers react differently -- some add extra `<em>`s to straighten things out and italicize the rest of the page, some ignore the error, etc.

**Diagnosis and Solutions:**

This is happening because the node has HTML, and the maximum length in your display happens to break inside of an italic block for that node.

This is could be caused by one or more of the following. (Tough to tell witch without knowing how you set up the page, but all should be easy for you to check)

1) The node's HTML is incorrectly written. (Solution: fix the code so that all tags are correctly closed)

2) The "Preview" of the node is left to be determined automatically. If you're using Full HTML in a node, you should always set the teaser manually so you don't get orphaned tags in the preview.

3) In Views, you have the "Trim this field to a maximum length" checked. If so, you should also use the "Field can contain HTML" option, since this forces Drupal's built-in HTML corrector to run

4) You have another module that's doing something similar to the options described above. That module might have it's own HTML correction options, or you can use Drupal's built-in corrector (`admin/settings/filters/%your-filter`)

Comment: I've been lucky to meet you. You saved me a lot of time. thanks!